Traveling Salesman question about algorithms
When thinking about the Traveling Salesman problem (limited to just 2 dimensions), and trying to find a minimal path that goes through each point, it seems like a matter of sorting the coordinates by some algorithm, albeit a polynomial time algorithm is currently unknown. I figure this is the case, because in 1-dimension along a circle, the Traveling Salesman problem would be trivial to solve in polynomial time, just sort all the points by their given angle. Is there any flaw in this logic? Assuming there isn't a flaw, I am curious if anyone has tried solving the Traveling Salesman problem by constructing a sorting algorithm for the 2-d points?

"sweep heuristic"

I’m voting to close this question because you show no thought of your own. The TSP is a sorting problem - it asks for the right sort order. Mathemticians have spent lots of time looking for solutions. Do some research on what's known.

It is not clear what you mean by "2d points".  Do you mean a planar graph?

I am not asking for a solution, I was just asking if my logic seemed sound. I have been trying to do research and have some original thought. I had never heard of it as a sorting problem before, I have only seen brute force things like dynamic programming. I have looked into things like the Concord solver. I thought I would ask some questions on here because sometimes being new to some of this makes it hard to know where to look. When I have asked questions in the past on where to look, those questions get deleted. Is this not a forum for open inquiry?

Yeah 2d could be planar or spherical coordinates (in the case of trying to solve for real cities on earth).
